# Pass a Python Variable containing multiple ID Numbers into external BigQuery Script

Tags: python, sql, function, google-bigquery

I have created a python class, and one of my methods is meant to take in either a single ID number or a list of ID numbers. The function will then use the ID numbers to query from a table in BigQuery using a .sql script. Currently, the function works fine for a single ID number using the following:

```
def state_data(self, state, id_number):

    if state == 'NY': 
        sql_script = self.sql_scripts['get_data_ny']
    else:
        sql_script = self.sql_scripts['get_data_rest']
         
    sql_script = sql_script.replace('@@id_number@@', id_number)
```

I'm having issues with passing in multiple ID numbers at once. There are 3 different ways that I've tried without success:

- The above method, passing in the multiple ID numbers as a tuple to use with `WHERE ID_NUM IN('@@id_number@@')`. This doesn't work, as when the .sql script gets called, a syntax error is returned, as parentheses and quotes are automatically added. For example, the SQL statement attempts to run as `WHERE ID_NUM IN('('123', '124')')`. This would run fine without one of the two sets of parentheses and quotes, but no matter what I try to pass in, they always get added.
- The second technique I have tried is to create a table, populate it with the passed in ID numbers, and then join with the larger table in BQ. It goes as follows:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TABLE ID_Numbers
(
     ID_Number STRING
);

INSERT INTO ID_Numbers (ID_Number)
VALUES ('@@id_number@@');

-- rest of script is a simple left join of the above created table with the BQ table containing the data for each ID
```

This again works fine for single ID numbers, but passing in multiple VALUES (in this case ID Numbers) would require a `('@@id_number@@')` per unique ID. One thing that I have not yet attempted - to assign a variable to each unique ID and pass each one in as a new VALUE. I am not sure if this technique will work.

- The third technique I've tried is to include the full SQL query in the function, rather than calling a .sql script. The list of ID numbers get passed in as tuple, and the query goes as follows:

```
id_nums = tuple(id_number)
query = ("""SELECT * FROM `data_table`
WHERE ID_NUM IN{}""").format(id_nums)
```

This technique also does not work, as I get the following error:
`AttributeError: 'QueryJob' object has no attribute 'format'`.
I've attempted to look into this error but I cannot find anything that helps me out effectively.

Finally, I'll note that none of the posts asking the same or similar questions have solved my issues so far.

I am looking for any and all advice for a way that I can successfully pass a variable containing multiple ID numbers into my function that ultimately calls and runs a BQ query.

Comment: Could you provide a sample of your input data and expected results?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should be able to use `*args` to get the `id_numbers` as a sequence and `f-strings` and `str.join()` to build the SQL query:

```py
class MyClass:

    def state_data(self, state, *id_numbers):
        print(f"{state=}")
        query = f"""
            SELECT * FROM `data_table`
            WHERE ID_NUM IN ({", ".join(str(id_number) for id_number in id_numbers)})
        """
        print(query)


my_class = MyClass()

my_class.state_data("some state", 123)
my_class.state_data("some more state", 123, 124)
```

On my machine, this prints:

```
➜  sql python main.py
state='some state'

            SELECT * FROM `data_table`
            WHERE ID_NUM IN (123)
        
state='some more state'

            SELECT * FROM `data_table`
            WHERE ID_NUM IN (123, 124)
```

Comment: Thank you, this does seem to work in a normal IDE, but for some reason Jupyter Notebook gives issue to the """ with f-string. That is beside my issue though, thanks!

Comment: I've never worked with Jupyter notebooks, but I'm glad the issue is solved for you!